# How can I write this expression in DW 2.0 mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am using this expression in TM component in mule3 and I wants to migrate this in mule 4.Can anyone please help me to solve this issue

```
(payload splitBy "\n") map using (startIndex = 41,lastIndex = ((sizeOf $) - 1)){
     "Data" : $[[startIndex][0] .. [lastIndex][0]]
```

1. I am getting missing expression error
2. using() is deprecated, replace with do-block
3. 

> Unable to call: `splitBy` with arguments: (`String | Null`, `"\\n"`).
> Reasons:
>
> - Expecting Type: `String`, but got: `Null`.        |-- From: `String`          |- From: splitBy(text: `String`, separator: `String`) ->
>   `Array<String>`                   4| (payload splitBy "\n") map using (startIndex =
>   41,lastIndex = ((sizeOf $) - 1)){
>   ^^^^^^^
> - Expecting Type: `String`, but got: `Null`.        |-- From: `String`
> - Expecting Type: `Regex`, but got: `"\\n"`.        |-- From: `Regex`           |- From: splitBy(text: `String`, regex: `Regex`) ->
>   `Array<String>`                   4| (payload splitBy "\n") map using (startIndex =
>   41,lastIndex = ((sizeOf $) - 1)){
>   ^^^^^^^

when I tried same expression in mule 4

Thanks In advance to all who can try to help me

Comment: The expression does not make sense, what is it trying to do? You expression has `[startIndex][0]` which is literally equal to `startIndex`. Are you split text into separate lines and then map each line after trimming from index `41`?

Comment: @Saksham_Nishu did you perform any investigation on how to migrate on your own? You are expected to investigate issues before posting a question on Stackoverflow. For example the `using` error should have pointed you into investigating the changes to DataWeave language. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details on what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

As stated you can change your expression to use `do` instead of `using`.
The `..` will be replaced by `to` for getting the substring

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload splitBy "\n") map  do {
    var startIndex = 41
    var lastIndex = sizeOf($) - 1
    ---
    { 
        "Data" : $[[startIndex][0] to [lastIndex][0]]
    }
}
```

Note that `[startIndex][0]` is same as `startIndex` so you can replace  `$[[startIndex][0] to [lastIndex][0]]` with  `$[startIndex to lastIndex]`

Also if the `startIndex` is really static and do not depend on the element, you can reduce your expression with

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var startIndex = 41
---
payload
 splitBy "\n" 
 map { 
    "Data" : $[startIndex to (sizeOf($) -1)]
 }
```